# TypeError (type 'User' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Either<Error, User>>'), even with same type return value

Tags: flutter, dart

how to properly assign a return value to a `Future<Either<Error, User>>>`? Because I alway getting: 
`_TypeError (type 'User' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Either<Error, User>>') as required by the closure's context'`
I even gave a **same type** return value.

```dart
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';

class APIPenggunaHelper {
  final api=APIPengguna();
  Future<Either<Error,User>> ambildatauser() async{
    final hasilapi=await api.ambilSemuaData();
    return hasilapi.fold((l){
      // handling error
      if(hasilapi.length()<1) return Left(MasalahDataKosong());
      return Left(Masalah400());
    }, (r){
      // handling result
      print(r.toString());
      final user_= User.fromJson(jsonDecode(r));
      return Right(user);
    });
  }
}
```

The code above should return **user** which is a `User` *class* as it should be, but it shows `subtype error` which I mention above.

This is the output from `print(r.toString())`

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  .
  .
  .
  ]
```

**EDIT:**

API.dart

```dart
class APIPengguna {
  final String linkpengguna='/users';
  Future<Either<Exception, dynamic>> ambilSemuaData() async{
    try {
      final mapbodi={
        "id":1,
        "username":"Bret"
      };
      // final uriapi=Uri.https('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',linkpengguna);
      final uriapi='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'+linkpengguna;
      Response respon=await get(uriapi);
      var status=respon.statusCode;
      var data=respon.body;
      // print('data: $data');
      if (status<200 || status>400) {
        throw new Exception('gagal ambil data');
      } else {
        return Right(data);     // data is a dynamic
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return (Left(Exception('gagal ambil data, eror: $e')));
    }
  }
}
```

list_user.dart

```dart
import 'package:appsa/aplikasi/perpustakaan.dart';

class DaftarUser{
  final List<User> pengguna;

  DaftarUser({this.pengguna});

  factory DaftarUser.fromJson(List<dynamic> jsonuser){
    List pengguna_=new List();
    pengguna_=jsonuser.map((p)=>User.fromJson(p)).toList();

    return new DaftarUser(
      pengguna:pengguna_
    );
  }
}
```

model_User.dart

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class User {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String username;
  final String email;
  final Address address;
  final String phone;
  final String website;
  final Company company;
  User({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.username,
    this.email,
    this.address,
    this.phone,
    this.website,
    this.company,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
      'address': address?.toMap(),
      'phone': phone,
      'website': website,
      'company': company?.toMap(),
    };
  }

  static User fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    if (map == null) return null;

    return User(
      id: map['id']?.toInt(),
      name: map['name'],
      username: map['username'],
      email: map['email'],
      address: Address.fromMap(map['address']),
      phone: map['phone'],
      website: map['website'],
      company: Company.fromMap(map['company']),
    );
  }

  String toJson() => jsonEncode(toMap());

  static User fromJson(String source) => fromMap(jsonDecode(source));

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'User(id: $id, name: $name, username: $username, email: $email, address: $address, phone: $phone, website: $website, company: $company)';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your return type for ambildatauser function as

```
Future<Either<Error,User>> ambildatauser() async{...}
```

But your function is actually returning a value of the type of User

You will have to change it to 
    `return Right(user);`

Comment: I've add `User u=User.fromJson(jsonDecode(r))`, but now it show same error with different type, which is `_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')`

Comment: It looks like somewhere you are mapping a list as a string . Can you post the model and the user class code?

Comment: If you check your `r.toString()` it a List of JSON objects whereas your user model expects a single JSON object. Maybe that's why it throwing the type error

Comment: I've make a list parser, change a bit to my code, and it still showing `not a subtype error`.

Comment: and yes, the `r.toString()` is returning a `List` in JSON, but its type is `dynamic`

Comment: I don't see anywhere you are using the list parser, can you try out this `List<User> userFromJson(String str) => List<User>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => User.fromJson(x)));
`  and `List<User> users =  userFromJson(r);`

Comment: it showing `Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')` on __x__ variable,